# Shifting Characters (ASCII values) to the left and right.

Tags: java, ascii, bit-shift

Using Java, I have to Implement a Java code that grabs a character, say A, B, C, D, E etc and Also a shift value (int) and whatever the shift value be, shift the character to that left and right using the shift value.

Example: A is entered, Shift value = 2 
       It Then Outputs A which becomes C (Shifted two to the right) and Y (Shifted two characters to the left)

Comment: Is this your Homework? Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes It is, I'm Not asking for code (Thats silly of me to ask :P) 
I just need help on how to start or what I should be researching to find out how to do it? etc..

Any Sort of Help really!

Comment: Hint 1: Use String#charAt(int) to access individual characters from your input string. Hint 2: You can shift the character values using addition/subtraction. Hint 3: Use a StringBuilder to create the result string.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your characters in an `ArrayList<Character>`, then you can access them by index.

After that all you need to do is to first get the index of the entered `Character`, and then add and subtract the shifting value from the index. You can use the modulo `%` operator to make sure you don't go out of bounds.

You can find all the methods you need in the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) JavaDoc.

Comment: You can access characters by index directly from String. See my comment above. No Lists necessary imo.

Comment: @qqilihq: I know, but I think using a `List<Character>` is clearer and better design.

Comment: Hey, I am not allowed to use arrays in my answer, Dont ask me why, that is just what the teacher has assigned us to do.

Comment: Ok. Are there any other restrictions? You should include restrictions and other such information in your question.